# why @@error issue does not catch the error ID number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

I tried executing `SELECT 1/0` and then executing `SELECT @@ERROR` in SQL server. However, it does not catch the error ID as it's supposed to. I know that `@@ERROR` stores the value until a successful TSQL query is executed.

Why is this happening?

```sql
SELECT 1/0
SELECT @@ERROR
```

It should be giving answer like this:

`8134`

But it Returns:

`0`

[image]

Video link to for @@ERROR not working --
https://clipchamp.com/watch/Isn7KyXv549

Video link to @@ERROR working as expected --
https://clipchamp.com/watch/EqJ1cMrBwRS

Comment: Why don't you try using `try/catch` and see what happens?

Comment: @Stu Try/Catch works. But why is @@Error not catching the error message ID?

Comment: Because you are not trapping the error, SQL server throws the error and that's the end of your batch; when you select `@@error` it's for a new batch, where no error has occured.

Comment: According to my understanding a different batch starts when you use Keyword GO. Right? Here I'm writing the SQL query line after line (I have added a screenshot in the post)

Comment: `GO` tells SSMS to submit a new batch if it's part of the selected text you submit, it has no influence on your batch being ended by SQL Server on error, which is what happens of you do not trap the error.

Comment: @AlokBajaj There are _many reasons_ SQL Server Management Studio might submit statements as a new batch. `GO` is one of them. Running only a portion of the code is another, and in fact every time you press F5 or use the run button on the tool you have a separate batch from whatever came before.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It's working fine in other laptop. Even when executed in separate batches. For some it's working fine and for some it's not. And we're following exactly the same steps. Even tried restarting the SQL sever and SSMS. But there's no change.

Comment: @Stu I'm not running @@error on its own. I highlighted and executed SELECT 1/0 first, and then SELECT @@ERROR.

Comment: I'm guessing you might have ANSI_WARNINGS off on the server where it isn't returning the error number for you.

Comment: https://clipchamp.com/watch/Isn7KyXv549    I've added a video for better understanding

Comment: @SeanLange Just tried same with SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF and ON. Makes no difference.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. I can't reproduce the issue you are encountering.

Comment: https://clipchamp.com/watch/EqJ1cMrBwRS              here's the video on different laptop using same SQL query. Here's it's working as expected

Comment: To be honest - clipchamp.com/watch/Isn7KyXv549 shows the correct behavior. If you first highlight the line "SELECT 1/0" + press F5 and afterwards you highlight the line "SELECT @@ERROR" + press F5 - it's like executing 2 different queries in two different windows.
You can also try this with this code:
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
SET @i = @i + 1;
PRINT @i;
If you highlight each of the line separately + press F5 the other lines don't about the previous run (= expected behaviour).
Why your example is working in clipchamp.com/watch/EqJ1cMrBwRS I'm not sure, yet, but it's definititely not expected

Comment: I was able to reproduce this behavior. In SSMS 18 you I've the same behavior like you in video 1. And in SSMS 19 I've the same behavior like in video 2. Not sure if SSMS 19 keeps the batch open in case of an error. However, my previous statement is still valid - in general if you execute single statements with F5 the next one does not know about the previous run (like if you execute DECLARE @i INT = 0; SET @i = @i + 1; PRINT @i; seperately line by line) - this is also the case in SSMS 19 (+ as said the expected behavior).

Comment: Ok - just for completion and for all interested in technical background ;-). If you run the profiler in SSMS 18 - you can see that it runs first: "SELECT 1/0" then it runs (not visible for you in the background) "SELECT @@SPID" (which resets the internal @@ERROR variable) and then it runs "SELECT @@ERROR". While in SSMS 19 (+ profiler) it runs only "SELECT 1/0" and then "SELECT @ERROR". Therefore sometimes it works sometimes not - so don't rely on this - only in case you run both statements at once (= highlighting both lines and press f5 will assure running in one batch).

Comment: @Twinnie why don't you make that an answer? It does seem the connection stays open if the query window has not been closed.

Comment: It really helped me to get more clarity on this topic by reading your comments. Thank you all for your suggestions and help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this behavior of video 1 in SSMS 18 and of video 2 in SSMS 19. I added a profiler to check what happens here.

In general - if you highlight single lines and press f5 SSMS is running these as separate batches - so e. g. in case you run

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0; 
SET @i = @i + 1;
```

separately, the second line will fail with "Must declare the scalar variable @i." - because each one is a separate batch (and doesn't know about the run before).

This happens also in case you run these lines seperately

```
SELECT 1/0
SELECT @@ERROR
```

The difference is here only, that @@ERROR is a global variable and can be selected independent from any batches before.

---

Why do you get a different result? If you attach the profiler you can see that SSMS 18 runs these statements:

```
SELECT 1/0
SELECT @@SPID -- (not visible and not triggered by you but by SSMS 18 in the background and thus resetting @ERROR to 0)
SELECT @@ERROR
```

while SSMS 19 really executes only

```
SELECT 1/0
SELECT @@ERROR
```

(in case you are fast enough and not other code is executed in the background by e. g. by any job between these 2 statements).

So, you cannot rely that @@ERROR will be kept between 2 manual run batches. Only if you highlight both lines and execute them together (press F5) in a single batch it should return the correct @@ERROR code.

Comment: @@ERROR and all the @@xxx expressions are technically system functions not variables.

Comment: "Only if you highlight both lines and execute them together (press F5) in a single batch it should return the correct @@ERROR code." depends if you have `SET XACT_ABORT ON` then you don't get any result at all. You can also put `GO` in the middle to execute them in separate batches in one run.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Although your comment is off-topic ;-) according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 the @@ERROR and @@ROWCOUNT are seen as variable while ERROR_NUMBER() is a function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 4):

> I know that @@ERROR stores the value until a successful TSQL query is executed.

That's not the only reason `@@ERROR` resets. It's also specific to a batch. *You are running these commands as **two separate batches***.

And in fact, when I run the two commands together on my system, I get two result sets. The first is empty (it failed), and the second has the value `8134`.

Comment: I'm not running them in different batches.

Comment: @AlokBajaj Just because they're on the screen together in SSMS doesn't mean they are in the same batch.

Comment: I've added a picture in the post. If you can check it please? And apologies for bad picture quality. First time posting here :)

Comment: @AlokBajaj If you highlight and press F5 or click the toolbar to run the highlighted text, **that is a separate batch**.

Comment: For some it works and for some it doesn't. I checked on friend's laptop and it's working fine. @@ERROR is able to catch the error message ID on his laptop. But not working in mine while doing exactly the same procedure.

Comment: @AlokBajaj select both statements together and press F5

Comment: @Charlieface it works while highlighting and executing both statement at once. But @@ERROR is supposed to hold the value until next successful query is executed. I tried this with some friends. We tried same steps. For some it works. For some it's not working.

Comment: @AlokBajaj *"@@ERROR is supposed to hold the value until next successful query is executed"* where do you get that from?

Comment: @Charlieface I mean, Once I get a runtime error, the message ID of that error can be captured by @@ERROR. Once I run a successful query, @@ERROR will be reset to 0.  I have shared the links of video of @@ERROR working as expected and not working using same steps.

Comment: Not sure on the second video where it seemed to work, but I saw nothing unusual in the first video. Every point where @@error failed to meet your expectations either it was run in a separate batch or the earlier error was a type that could fail the whole batch, before the `select @@error` had a chance to execute

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn interesting I get different results depending on whether I select each statement, or if instead just put `GO` between them. Perhaps the connection gets recycled in the first case, as it doesn't seem to be purely batch-scoped. `XACT_ABORT` doesn't seem to make a difference unless it's all one batch.

Comment: @Charlieface: Check my comment on the answer above. On the video Alok is running each statement separately with F5, while SSMS is running some background query (checked with profiler) between those manual runs and therefore resetting the @@ERROR variable.